# return from recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have recursive function which looks thru deeply nested object or array of ojbects and finds wanted object by key. Problem is when i want to return result object i get undefined and i dont know why. When i console log result i get correct result.

```
function checkForDependency(name, scope) {
    if (Array.isArray(scope)) {
        scope.forEach((el) => {
            return checkForDependency(name, el)
        })
    } else if (typeof scope === 'object') {
        if (scope.hasOwnProperty('name') && scope.name == name && scope.hasOwnProperty('dependency')) {
            console.log('dependency:', scope.dependency)
            return {
                type: scope.dependency
            }
        } else {
            for (let key in scope) {
                if (Array.isArray(scope[key]) || typeof scope[key] === 'object') {
                    return checkForDependency(name, scope[key])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: whats the type of input you are using to get the wrong result?

Comment: Please click `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: Can you please provide a sample input to this function

Comment: You have an `if` followed by an `else if`...where is the `else` block. Same goes for inside your `else if` block, the `for-loop` has nothing after it. If this is a recursive function, you cannot afford to leave any path way untouched, and this is probably why you are getting undefined at times

Comment: I guess the problem is your .forEach function. In line 4 you are returning from an anonymous function you are not returning from your actual recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a temporary variable with early exit an a check if the temporary variable has a value, then exit the function.

You need not to check for array, because you could iterate the keys of the array or as an object, which is the same.

```
function checkForDependency(name, scope) {
    var temp;
    if (typeof scope !== 'object') {                    // early exit if no object
        return;
    }
    if (scope.name === name && 'dependency' in scope) { // check value and key
        console.log('dependency:', scope.dependency)
        return { type: scope.dependency };              // return found value
    }
    if (Object.keys(scope).some(key => temp = checkForDependency(name, scope[key]))) {
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Elegant solution. Thank you very much :)